# Tratamento de erro não funciona

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, microsoft-azure

No config da minha aplicação eu deletei o customErrors para fazer um teste de um erro que está dificil de replicar.

E onde deve estar acontecendo o erro eu coloquei um try:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.TarefaHoras.Add(tarefaHora);

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException ex)
            {
                ErroDetalhe erro = new ErroDetalhe();
                erro.Data = tarefaHora.Data;
                erro.UsuarioId = tarefaHora.ApplicationUserId;
                erro.JSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tarefaHora);
                erro.Tipo = "TarefaHora";
                erro.Controller = "TarefaHoras";
                erro.Action = "Create Post";
                erro.Exception = ex.GetType().FullName;

                db.ErroDetalhes.Add(erro);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("ErroNaAtualizacaoDaBase", "Erros", new { id = erro.ID });                        
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        ViewBag.TipoTarefaID = new CBMMSapp.DAO.TiposTarefaDAO().ListaParaDropDown();
        ViewBag.ApplicationUserId = new CBMMSapp.DAO.UsuariosDAO().ListaParaDropDown(tarefaHora.ApplicationUserId);
        ViewBag.ClienteID = new CBMMSapp.DAO.ClientesDAO().ListaParaDropDown();
        return View(tarefaHora);
    }
```

Esse erro só acontece em tempo de execução e só no servidor da Azure, então minha tentativa era de receber uma descrição melhor do erro e para isso criei uma tabela onde são depositadas as informações.

Mas....

O problema é que a View de erro que estou recebendo não é a View ErroNaAtualizacaoDaBase que eu criei e que é redirecionada no Catch.

É a View de erro padrão do AspNET.

Então fui nas Shared views e excluí a página padrão e retirei do web.config o customErrors.

E mesmo assim o Azure ainda traz a View de erro padrão.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Remove o SaveChanges de dentro do catch. Se é ali o erro, vc deve estar tendo uma ex não tratada.

Answer (score 0):

Ola,

Uma maneira simples de validar ter o StackTrace do seu erro, seria habilitar os FREB Logs no seu App Service.

> FREB LOGS: informações detalhadas sobre solicitações com falha, incluindo um rastreamento dos componentes IIS usados para processar a solicitação e o tempo levado em cada componente. Isto pode ser útil se você está tentando melhorar o desempenho do site ou isolar o que está causando o retorno de um erro específico de HTTP.

- No portal acesse o slot do app service desejado e depois navegue até: Settings > Diagnostic Logs
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- Habilite a opção Failed request tracing.
- No slot do app service desejado navegue até Diagnose and solve problems
- No topo selecione a opção Troubleshoot e na lista de Tools, selecione FREB logs
- Uma nova tela será carregada e na listagem podemos ter acesso a diversas informações, inclusive ao xml com todo de detalhe do IIS sobre o erro.

Para mais detalhes:
https://rafaeldossantos.net/azure-failed-request-tracing-analisando-erros-de-forma-simples/

Comment: Hi Rafael, I'm guessing from your questions on SO that you understand english, so! I suggest you take a read of this [How not to be a spammer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and then edit your question to prevent it being deleted

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Resposta editada conforme sugestao. Obrigado pessoal